# Application showing different behavior for Start Button from different pages in application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have about 3-4 different pages in my app.When the main page of my app is displayed and Start key is pressed,Home screen of device appears.Now when Back key is pressed,it bring back the Main page of my app which is the expected behavior.But if i enter into my app and open the second or third page and then perform the same Start and Back button action,then  my app is not resumed from the page it left from.Instead,an app that was opened prior to my app opens.
How can i rectify the behavior?

Comment: Can you show your navigate event handlers for the second page (if you have any) and PhoneApplicationService Activated/Deactivated event handlers?

Comment: Phone Activated/Deactivated event handlers are not used and navigates event handlers are performing action specific to the page. with base.OnNavigatedTo() and base.OnNaviageetdFrom()

Comment: My guess was that you could have unhandled exception raised inside one of the methods I mentioned. If you are not using Activated event to restore state then maybe you are trying to use some destroyed object after your application comes back to life which results in an exception?

Comment: Might be this is the problem..Can u provide some help on how to store the state of app when deactivated?

Comment: First of all make sure that is the problem - run your app in debug mode in Visual Studio, navigate to the second page, press "Start" then "Back" and see, whether any exception is being thrown. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Loki Kriasus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499285/loki-kriasus), this type of behavior definitely sounds like you are trying to use objects that have not been initialized when your application is restored.  Charles Petzold's free eBook [Programming Windows 7](http://charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) has a great section on this starting on page 117.

For what you are doing, I would guess the **Phone State** would be more than adequate.  The Phone State is similar to Session State in ASP.NET.  It is just a dictionary of (serializable) objects with string keys and is not maintained across launches of your app, but it is restored when your app is navigated to from the Back Stack.

Here is an example of it's use to restore some custom object named myObject:

```
private CustomObject myObject;

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
    //Save to State when leaving the page
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"] = myObject;
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("myObject"))
    {
        //Restore from State
        myObject = (CustomObject)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"];
    }
    else
    {
        //No previous object, so perform initialization
        myObject = new myObject();
    }
}
```

If you need to store settings across all instances of your app then look into [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which is perfect for this. There are other options depending on your needs (check the linked book above for examples).  I would guess using the Page State as shown above in your 2nd and 3rd pages will fix your problem.

Comment: thanx a lot @theChrisKent..It really help me understand the functionality.But i want to save the state of complete page.Is it possible to do this?